# flex: loading local flash file

Tags: apache-flex, flash

i'm pretty new to flex 3 but it's really cool so far.
i have embedded 2 mxml components thank to you guys,
now in the center of the screen when i try to load an swf file using the SWFLoader object
i get the following error:

> Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2140: Security
>   sandbox violation:
>   file:///C:/Users/ufk/Documents/Flex%20Builder%203/GamePage/bin-debug/GamePage.swf
>   cannot load
>   file:///C:/Users/ufk/Documents/Flex%20Builder%203/GamePage/bin-debug/crazy_counting.swf.
>   Local-with-filesystem and local-with-networking SWF files cannot load
>   each other.

code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
   `<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" backgroundGradientColors="[0xFFFFFF,0xAAAAAA]" xmlns:local="*">`
    `<local:AchievementsVBox x="0" y="0"  height="531"/>`
        `<mx:SWFLoader id="game_swf" source="crazy_counting.swf" x="198" y="0" width="721" height="531"/>`
    `<local:LiveScoringSystemVBox x="918" y="0"  height="531" width="218"/>
</mx:Application>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Project/Properties/Flex Compiler/Additional compiler arguments` and make sure that both SWF's are compiled with `-use-network=false` flag. If one of the SWF's can talk to network, you cannot load a local SWF into it (the reverse is also true).

Answer (score 0):

Flash has numerous security restrictions to stop malicious code getting run on your machine.

As you know this particular case is fine, try going to the flash security page and add the url you to your bin-debug folder.  It *should* stop the error message from appearing and should load the swf fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can make both of the swf locally trusted then it should load.

Answer (score 0):

using the SWFLoader, i can declare the source as source="@Embed(source='file.swf')"
by using the Embed i am able to load local files without changing compilation flags because the swf file is actually compiled into the flex application and not loaded dynamically.

i still prefer using use-network=false because i need the files to be loaded dynamically, but it's just another answer if anyone needs it.